# How to connect to a Wi-Fi device but use cell data

Tags: wi-fi, mobile-data

I have a Wi-Fi connection on a solar system that connects to an app to provide data on usage. I do not have Internet aside from my phone on my property. I need to connect to the Wi-Fi solar  Data logger but continue to use my cell data connection, as it requires Internet to function properly

Comment: AFAIR only the latest Android version(s) allow to be connected to a Wifi without Internet access and continue to use mobile data.